# Shall I use Visual Studio Express or Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-phone, visual-studio-2013

I have just downloaded "Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Phone" to start Windows phone development. This is a free software. But I also came to know that you can also do Windows phone development using Visual Studio 2013 which is paid software.

Is there a disadvantage using Express edition for Windows phone development? Like it doesn't come with all features, libraries and APIs etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do development of a Windows Phone app with Visual Studio Express with complete access to all APIs.

However, the Express edition is limited. You cannot mix project types (Web and Phone) in one solution and there is limited support for Add-Ins like CodeRush.

Whether limited support of plugins or the lack of mixed solutions bother is up to you. If the bucks you would spent do a return of investment is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

All two works perfect! You can make apps in any version created for WP.